# failed on install silent SQL express use command prompt

Tags: command-prompt, installshield, sql-server-express, silent-installer

I'm trying to made a setup using installshield2015 with SQL Server Express silent install, and I need "SQLExpress2008 SP1 86,64bit WOW" or another version as prerequisite, I set "specify command line for the application" with these values:

```
/qs /INSTANCEID="SQLEXPRESS" /ACTION="Install" /FEATURES=SQLENGINE 
    /INSTANCENAME="SQLEXPRESS" /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" 
    /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Builtin\Administrators" /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN
```

and also I tested with other values for each one of variables, but SQL Server Express always fails to setup. When I use manual config or step by step setup for SQL Server Express, everything is OK.

What should i do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXps6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a way to know what is the exactly problem occurred during installation, you can found a log file in "SqlSetup.log" at temp windows folder.

Comment: Okay, it's nice that you found the logs, but what is the fix to your problem?

Comment: unfortunately The problem still exists! I made another question about code errors but nobody did not answer yet!                               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39442265/fails-on-setup-of-sql-server-express-silent-installation-with-exit-codes-0x84b4

Comment: You could have editted this question rather than essentially reposting