# Fails on setup of SQL Server Express silent Installation with Exit Codes: 0x84B40003 and 0x84C40013

Tags: installation, command-prompt, sql-server-express, exit-code, silent-installer

I'm trying to made a setup using Installshield 2015 with SQL Server Express silent install, I set "specify command line for the application" with these values:

```
SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe /QS /FEATURES=SQLEngine,Replication,Conn 
        /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms=1 /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic 
        /ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=SQLExpress /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" 
        /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS" 
        /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic 
        /ERRORREPORTING=0 /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=""  
        /RSSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic
```

SQL Server Express fails to setup and when checked `SqlSetup.log` that is located in the "Windows Temp Folder" I saw these lines:

> 09/10/2016 05:23:55.076 Process returned exit code: 0x84B40003
>
> 09/10/2016 05:23:55.248 Workflow RUNRULES /RULES=GlobalRules returned exit code: 0x84B40003
>
> 09/10/2016 05:23:57.881 Setup closed with exit code: 0x84C40013

Does anyone know what these codes meaning and what exactly I have to do ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following 
***setup.exe /action=repair***  *<< Modify to the Installer Instance*

Then make sure you have .NET 4.0 it is a requirement but isn't in the installer package of memory. Catches a lot of people.

Comment: I already installed visual studio 2013 on my computer, I'm 100 Percent sure the problem is not about .net framework. 
seems 0x84B40003 Code talk about "Windows Admin Permission" , but I have no idea about the another one !